# Cannot snap abort or sudo snap abort

Tags: snap

I can't remove a failed application

```
~$ snap changes
ID   Status  Spawn                   Ready                   Summary
38   Done    yesterday at 20:48 WIB  yesterday at 20:48 WIB  Auto-refresh snap "core18"
39   Error   today at 17:50 WIB      today at 18:10 WIB      Install "mc-installer" snap

~$ snap abort 39
error: cannot abort change 39 with nothing pending
```